# Natural $\Pi^1_2$ (or worse) classes of structures?

Tags: lo.logic, soft-question, examples, descriptive-set-theory

(To clarify, my interest is mainly *lightface*, that is, $\Pi^1_2$ instead of **$\bf \Pi^1_2$**, although it doesn't particularly matter.)

This is just an idle curiosity. In logic, I find myself frequently working with the countable ordinals; this is a $\Pi^1_1$ set of structures, in the sense that the set of reals coding well-orderings with domain $X\subseteq\omega$ is $\Pi^1_1$. This is also a fairly natural class of structures, of interest outside logic as well; and other interesting classes of structures - e.g., torsion groups, Artinian rings, infinite graphs into which a given infinite graph $G$ does not embed - are also $\Pi^1_1$ (and usually are vastly simpler than $\Pi^1_1$).

Obviously, there are more complicated classes of structures; however,  all the examples I know are pretty artificial. So my question is: what are some natural classes of countable structures, which are worse than $\Pi^1_1$?

In particular:

> Is there a natural class of countable structures which is $\Pi^1_2$ complete?

(Of course, what "natural" means is subjective. What I mean by natural here is "of roughly equal interest to non-logicians as well-orderings," but examples from within logic would be okay if there is an interesting argument to be made that they will someday be of interest outside logic.)

Comment: I suppose that all of these are boldface $\mathbf\Pi^1_n$, right?

Comment: I don't think so; e.g., the set of reals coding well-orderings is lightface $\Pi^1_1$.

Comment: I wonder about the goodness of the idea of using font weight (of Greek letters!) as an apparently significative notation in this case!

Comment: I tend to agree. It's standardized, unfortunately.

Comment: @Mariano: While I agree with your and Noah about this not necessarily being a good idea, there's an excellent reason for this notation and the relations between are excellent. That aside, you can see the boldface notation sometimes written as a lightface+under-tilde. This, I was told, is a result of "standard" boldface notation when writing on blackboards. Some papers I ran into used that notation instead. Amusingly, the same can be said about names in forcing, which were written as boldface letters, and then as under-tilded letters (as they are written today by some authors, e.g. Shelah).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example that comes to mind is the set of recursive dilators; this is a $\Pi^1_2$-complete set (Theorem 4.1 in Girard 1985, [Introduction to $\Pi^1_2$-logic](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00486046)). Dilators have some use outside of logic (e.g.: Some uses of dilators in combinatorial problems [I](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/conm/065/891241), [II](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2274952), [III](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01620619)).

**Added October 27:**

*Definition:* A dilator is functor from ON to ON (the large poset of ordinals and strictly increasing functions) preserving filtered colimits and pullbacks. A dilator is *weakly finite* if it maps finite ordinals to finite ordinals. A dilator is *recursive* if it is weakly finite and the morphism part is a recursive function from N to N under a standard coding of finite sequences as numbers.

Thus, weakly finite dilators are coded by reals, while recursive dilators are coded by numbers, and in the latter case forming a $\Pi^1_2$-complete set, just as the usual set of codes of recursive ordinals forms a $\Pi^1_1$-complete set.

Comment: I'm finding Girard alternately vague and difficult to read; what is a "recursive dilator?" My understanding is that a dilator is a functor from ON to ON preserving limits and pullbacks. The obvious (to me) way of recursifying this results in recursive dilators being indexed by natural numbers, which isn't exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I added the definitions. Rereading your question, I see you were looking at sets of reals, while my answer addresses subsets of $\omega$. But perhaps weakly finite dilators are a $\Pi^1_2$-complete set of reals?

Comment: Thanks! I'd definitely be interested in whether weakly finite dilators are a $\Pi^1_2$-complete set of reals - that certainly seems plausible.

Comment: Indeed, I think this is in [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01633985) by Ressayre. See Sec. 3 there (the objects are called ordered Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski models with finitely many function symbols, but I think they're the same thing as (codes of) weakly finite dilators). There are related notions (ptykes) at higher types that provide $\Pi^1_n$-complete notions, according to a [hard-to-find paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=791069) by Girard and Ressayre.

Comment: The abstract looks interesting; however, I have to ask: how is one supposed to pronounce "ptyx?" And why "ptyx" in the first place? http://www.jstor.org/stable/2907653

Comment: I found [Eléments de logique $\Pi^1_n$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/pspum/042/791069) after all. But I don't know how to pronounce ptyx/ptykes nor why Girard picked the name. :) BTW, don't bother tracing the second volume of Girard's book, _Proof theory and logical complexity_; it never appeared (I hear there are drafts out there, but I haven't seen any).

Comment: Girard has put *Proof theory and logical complexity II* on his site here: https://girard.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Archives4.html

Comment: Oh thanks, that's great!

Answer (score 8):

An example directly generalizing well-orderings is that the [better quasi-orderings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better-quasi-ordering) are $\Pi^1_2$-complete, shown in Marcone's aptly named [The Set of Better Quasi-Orders is $\Pi^1_2$](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.19950410309/abstract).

Comment: Very nice example!